# yocto won't pull in gitlab projects with too many underscores in the name. Anyone know a fix?

Tags: gitlab, yocto

```
DESCRIPTION = "common data for the FRMCS project, used by FRMCS libraries and applications"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""
DEPENDS = ""

PR = "r1.0"
SRCREV = "v0.1"

SRC_URI = "git://git@xxxxxx.com:/frmcs/**frmcs_common_data**.git;protocol=ssh"

# frmcs-common-data is a header-only C++ library, so the main package will be empty.

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

BUILDDIR = "${WORKDIR}/build"

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
```

Comment: Please provide the fetch error.

Comment: It's ok, yocto did not like the url format.  job done... until the next time! :-)